# zig link: how to link against shared (system) libraries?

Tags: zig

I want zig to link in shared (dynamic) system libraries (like pthread). No matter what I try, Zig links in static libs. Now, generally I prefer that, but not in this case. How/where do I communicate this Zig behavior.

Here's what I get every single time:

```
$ ldd ./zig-out/bin/zig-perftest
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd97d3d000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fdf16a74000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fdf16d5f000)
```

Here's what I want (below from C build with clang (no zig)):

```
$ ldd ./raw_ethernet_bw
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd139e0000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f73a646f000)
libmlx5.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmlx5.so.1 (0x00007f73a63f1000)
libefa.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libefa.so.1 (0x00007f73a63e4000)
librdmacm.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librdmacm.so.1 (0x00007f73a63c5000)
libibverbs.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libibverbs.so.1 (0x00007f73a63a2000)
libpci.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpci.so.3 (0x00007f73a6390000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f73a6168000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f73a65b2000)
libnl-3.so.200 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnl-3.so.200 (0x00007f73a6145000)
libnl-route-3.so.200 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnl-route-3.so.200
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f73a60a6000)
libudev.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1 (0x00007f73a607c000)
```

Here's build.zig:

```
exe.setTarget(target);                                                                                              
exe.setBuildMode(mode);                                                                                             
                                                                                                                    
// C compliation options                                                                                            
const cflags = [_][]const u8{                                                                                       
  "-D_GNU_SOURCE",                                                                                                  
  "-g",                                                                                                             
  "-O2",                                                                                                            
  "-Wall",                                                                                                          
  "-march=native",                                                                                                  
  "-std=c11",                                                                                                       
};                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                    
// C source code                                                                                                    
const sourceCodeFiles = [_][]const u8{                                                                              
  "./src/ib/ib_common.c",                                                                                           
  "./src/ib/ib_device.c",                                                                                           
};                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                    
// C include paths                                                                                                  
exe.addIncludePath("./src/ib");                                                                                     
exe.addIncludePath("/usr/include");                                                                                 
exe.addIncludePath("/usr/include/infiniband");                                                                      
exe.addIncludePath("/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu");                                                                
                                                                                                                    
// C linker paths                                                                                                   
exe.addLibraryPath("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu");                                                                    
                                                                                                                    
// C source code                                                                                                    
exe.addCSourceFiles(&sourceCodeFiles, &cflags);                                                                     
                                                                                                                    
// Link in glibc                                                                                                    
exe.linkLibC();                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                    
// And link in dependent IB libraries                                                                               
exe.linkSystemLibrary("mlx5");                                                                                      
exe.linkSystemLibrary("efa");                                                                                       
exe.linkSystemLibrary("rdmacm");                                                                                    
exe.linkSystemLibrary("ibverbs");                                                                                   
exe.linkSystemLibrary("pci");                                                                                       
exe.linkSystemLibrary("pthread");                                                                                   
exe.linkSystemLibrary("nl-route-3");                                                                                
exe.linkSystemLibrary("nl-3");                                 

// None of these flags help
exe.pie = true;                                                                                                     
exe.force_pic = true;                                                                                               
exe.verbose_link = true;                                                                                            
exe.linkage = std.build.LibExeObjStep.Linkage.dynamic;
```

Comment: https://github.com/ziglang/zig/issues/14939

Answer (score 0):

Your linking is dynamic.
There is no problem with your configuration.
Zig eliminates the dependencies because you don't call anything is these libraries.

Answer (score 0):

in zig version 0.11, there a new version of `linkSystemLibrary`. Try

```
exe.linkSystemLibrary2("pthread", .{ .preferred_link_mode = .Dynamic });
```

That makes the preferred link mode explicit.

But it's still true, that the linker removes unused objects.